# Line break in ASP is displayed as text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please I want to build this String below in the VB.net code behind an ASP.net page.
I tried several ways to make the line break but I did not succeed. Always the 
 is displayed as text. You can see the print screen of the HTML page down.
Thank you in advance.

```html
dim description as string = "A" + "<br/>" + "B"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd5mg.jpg)

Comment: It appears as though it is displaying the String literal and not the markup. How are you outputting the String?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to set the text via code-behind.

Front-End HTML

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

           <asp:Literal ID="ltlTest" runat="server" />

        </div>
    </form>
```

Code-Behind

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.ltlTest.Text = String.Format("Line 1 {0} Line 2 {0} Line 3 {0} Line 4", "<br />")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution.But the problem that i'm building a dynamic data grid from the code behind and after i send this string for cells .
Then i think that i cannot use your solution.

Comment: When you build your dynamic grid, you still have to put controls inside the cells (i.e. Literal).